# ERROR: Unable to find a bootable option. press any key to shut down

Tags: lumia-520, error

Has anyone ever had success recovering from the error? I just restarted my device. Before that everything seemed okay, but after the restart, the device showed the error.
Any advice? I looked up for the issue on the internet, but it's confusing.

UPDATE : already use the NSRT , the software recognize my device , but when it'll install the rom , suddenly the software said the device not recognized

Comment: have you tried a software reset or even the Nokia Software Recovery Tool?

Comment: @NeilTurner yep already use the NSRT , the software recognize my device , but when it'll install the rom , suddenly the software said the device not recognized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Found that ERROR: Unable to find a bootable option. press any key to shut down is caused by hardware failure, because I bring the device to nokia care center and I got machine replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You should certainly get the phone checked out by Nokia Service if you can't even fix it through NSRT.